# Openstack Failed to launch Instances [Error: No Valid Host was found]

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openvswitch

I have tried to install openstack on Centos 7.
Below are the configurations:

1. Neutron Node (VM with 2 Vcpu, 2 GB RAM , 3 NICs)
2. Controller Node(VM with 2 Vcpu, 8 GB RAM, 1 NIC)
3. Compute Node(Physical Machine 24 CPU, 64 GB RAM, 2 NIC)
   `# egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` gives an output of `24`

I have followed the online documentation: [OPENSTACK INSTALLATION GUIDE FOR RED HAT ENTERPRISE LINUX 7, CENTOS 7, AND FEDORA 20  - JUNO (Install and configure network node)](http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/yum/content/neutron-network-node.html) line by line and verified all configurations 3 times.

Now whenever I try to launch instances using the Horizon dashboard, I get this error `No Valid Host was found!!`

Nova-compute Log gives me this error

**Nova-compute.log**

> 2015-08-21 22:55:00.391 41235 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: d9bfa207->6e85-4ca8-a385-52d90818a49b]     _("Unexpected vif_type=%s") % vif_type)
>   2015-08-21 22:55:00.391 41235 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: d9bfa207->6e85-4ca8-a385-52d90818a49b] NovaException: Unexpected vif_type=binding_failed

These are my neutron and compute node network interfaces http://pastebin.com/vJyCy5zc

Nova.conf file on the Compute node
http://pastebin.com/RvYkUEfW

I have searched google, openstack forum and elsewhere and tried all their suggestions, but the issue remains unsolved.
Here is a link to my openstack-forum question: [Unable to launch instances (Unexpected vif_type=binding failed)](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/80530/)

Also note that I do not have any connectivity issues to the AMQP server on the controller, as I get successfully connected message in my logs.

All my openstack services are up and running properly
Has anyone faced a similar issue? I have been struggling with this issue, since last 2 weeks.
Any help will be deeply revered.

Comment: The `binding_failed` message indicates a problem with your Neutron configuration.  You should check in the agent log on your compute host (possibly `/var/log/neutron/openvswitch-agent.log`) and the server log (`/var/log/neutron/server.log`) on the controller, and update your question with any errors you find there.

Comment: please have a look at [http://pastebin.com/vJyCy5zc] for my n/w interfaces.
Logs are at [http://pastebin.com/aspEAFkt].

Comment: I got a workaround. I created another network with some other IP range(10.0.12.0/24) other than the already existing (203.0.113.0/24) N/w.
Now when i use this 10 series N/w to launch instances, i see a successful message, but when i try to use the 203 series , it again gives me the same binding failed error.
Can you sugggest what is causing this? And more importantly, how do i rectify this? Have a look at my interfaces as pasted in the above comment. 172 series is the management interface and 182 is the tunnel one. Thanks

Comment: Ok! some more info.....here is what i see in the subnet table under the neutron database. I see enable_dhcp set to 0 for the 203 series and 1 for the 10 series. This is perhaps the issue. But how do i fix it??

Comment: Ok enabled_ dhcp for the 203 series network, still same issue

Answer (score 1):

Modify /etc/nova/nova.conf file and increase the allocation ratio .
`cpu_allocation_ratio` and `memory_allocation_ratio` in compute node .
Restart the  nova and nova-scheduler service in compute node

`systemctl restart openstack-nova-*
 systemctl restart openstack-nova-scheduler.service`